# open proc/[pid]/stat on forked children

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am trying to call fopen("proc/{pid}/stats") on children processes
but the forked children seem to execute too fast in order to open
the data while it's still available.

I have tried the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nprocesses; i++){
    wait(&ids[i]);
    FILE *fd;
    char buf[100];
    char str1[] = "proc/";
    char str2[] = "/stats";
    itoa(ids[i], buf);
    strcat(str1, buf);
    strcat(str1, str2);

    char buf2[BUFSIZ];
    fd = fopen(str1, "r");
    while (fgets(buf2, BUFSIZ, temp) != NULL)
        ;
    printf("%s\n", buf2);
}
```

Is there any way to give the parent program more time so the data
can be opened and processed?

Comment: did you check the filename this generates... what did `perror` say?

Comment: 1. Reverse `strcat()` arguments. Destination is first. 2. Absolute path must begin with `/`. 3. /proc/<pid> entry is removed after `wait()`. Call `waitid()` with `WNOWAIT` flag, read stats and then call `waitpid()`/`waitid()` again.

Comment: Instead of `strcat()` you can compose name with `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/proc/%li"/stat", (long)ids[i])`